# uses the variable outside for loop statment

Tags: php, string, for-loop

i want to loop a variable and assign this variable in database i use this code

```
$chars = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789";    
$size = strlen( $chars );
for( $i = 0; $i < 10; $i++ ) {
    $str = $chars[ rand( 0, $size - 1 ) ];
}
```

if i use $str outside the for loop it will give me just 1 random character 
if i use it indside for loop it will give me random 10 character

how can i use this code to generate the random 10 characters ??

i tried to define the variable before loop string like this

$str = '';

but also not working for me..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Every time you do `$str = $chars[ rand( 0, $size - 1 ) ];` you are **replacing** `$str`'s value. To append, or concatenate, all the generated characters use the `.` operator, like:

```
$str .= $chars[ rand( 0, $size - 1 ) ];
```

This is the same as doing the following:

```
$str = $str . $chars[ rand( 0, $size - 1 ) ];
```

Documentation: http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php

Comment: I'd like to pedantically point out that, as mentioned on the manual page you linked to `.=` is technically a different operator from `.`; thinking of it as the same operator might lead to some wrong assumptions. That said, PHP has such a rich set of assignment operators, that most of the time just adding `=` to an operator does in fact result in a valid operator.

Answer (score 2):

add '.' (dot) to '=' for string concatenation - it give you 10 char string

```
$str = '';
for( $i = 0; $i < 10; $i++ ) {
    $str .= $chars[ rand( 0, $size - 1 ) ];
}

echo $str;
```

or

use [] to get array of chars

```
for( $i = 0; $i < 10; $i++ ) {
    $str[] = $chars[ rand( 0, $size - 1 ) ];
}

print_r($str);
```

Comment: Unless you state the variable outside the loop.. You will be overwriting

Comment: lol not me ... i can not mark any answer till now i am new here

Comment: @TelmoMarques Perhaps I was wrong in one aspect, but during the initial loop (0) you will be trying to append to a variable which has not been set prior to this.. So the first entry will trigger the notice, set the variable.. Then the other 9 times PHP enters the loop it will beable to append to the variable because it has been previously set.. Stand corrected, set the variable prior to the loop.

Comment: @user1477332 I never asked questions, but I think the questioner can always mark any answer as acceptable (but not earlier than 10-15 minutes after asking a question)

Comment: @DarylGill yes I agree, it's always good practice to initialize a variable.

Answer (score 1):

in php you append something to the string using the `.=` :

```
$str .= $chars[ rand( 0, $size - 1 ) ];
```